# A variation of "How to find the maximum area of a rectangle given its perimeter" with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, modeling, mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization problem with the following mathematical model. It is similar to finding the maximum area of a rectangle given its perimeter but in this example we don't have 2 variables.

I have `X` number of positive integers whose sum is `Y`. How can I find the set of integers that will give me the maximum of their multiplications given `Y`?

Example:

Given that `Y =  8` the answer should be `X[1] = 2; x[2] = 3; x[3] = 3` since that will give me the maximum of multiplications.

Any python code/logic for this kind of problem?

Comment: I don't have a formal proof of this, but I would be willing to bet that the maximum area would be given by the equilateral triangle ...

Comment: Am I missing something? Shouldnt that be `X[1] = 2; x[2] = 2; x[3] = 2`?

Comment: Looks like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle#Famous_theorems) agrees with me.

Comment: @mgilson I think that might be a step in the right direction, but I think he's looking for an n-dimensional solution where n is either user-defined or one of the variables to be discovered.

Comment: @sr2222 -- Yeah, I know that's not the solution (which is why I posted it as a comment).

Comment: That's correct in my model number of variables is also a variable. @thefourtheye, sum of 2,2,2 is 6 so that's not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let n be the number of items, and s the sum. Populate the list of size n with `s // n` and add 1 to the last `s % n` elements. This gives you the list with the max product.

```py
max_list = [s//n] * (n - s%n) + [s//n + 1] * (s%n)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the “maximum of multiplications will be when all the values are nearest to equal values”, as stated in a previous answer and implemented via
`max_list = [s//n] * (n - s%n) + [s//n + 1] * (s%n)`
in another answer.  This can be justified by techniques similar to those used in proving the arithmetic-mean to geometric-mean inequality, as in (for example) [Proof by Pólya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_P.C3.B3lya_using_the_exponential_function).

When the sum Y is given but not the number of terms X,  and it's desired to compute X, observe that `pow(W,Y/W)` is maximal when `W = e ≃ 2.71828`.  The integer nearest to `e` is 3, so to maximize the product, include mostly 3's, and one or two 2's.  In general, include two 2's when Y%3 is 1, and one 2 when Y%3 is 2, and none when Y%3 is 0, and make up the difference with 3's.  Examples (in the form, [Y:a b...] for sum Y and terms a,b,...) include [3: 3], [4: 2 2], [5: 3 2], [6:3 3], [7: 3 2 2], [8: 3 3 2], [9:3 3 3], [10: 3 3 2 2] and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of multiplications will be when all the values are nearest to equal values.

```
X = [Y // 3 for i in range(3)]
difference = Y - X[0] * 3
if difference == 2:
    x[0] += 1
    X[1] += 1
elif difference == 1:
    X[0] += 1
print (X)

Output:
Y = 8
X = [3, 3, 2]
Y = 9
X = [3,3,3]
Y = 10
X = [4,3,3]
```

Comment: Isn't that assuming that there should be 3 variables? What if for some certain cases, the optimum solution has 4 variables?

Comment: @PaulMiles: Do you have any example in mind in which 4 variables gives optimum solution?

Comment: For Y=10, there are more than 1 optimal solutions i.e. {2,2,3,3} ; {4,3,3} etc. With this model we are missing out the first.

Comment: @PaulMiles: As other answers suggest one optimal solution will always be having 3 numbers. And if we want to find the other optimal solutions I think we will have to go for some dynamic programming solution..